# putting Nans in columns that aren't within start/end numbers for each row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to work out a way to put a nan in columns that don't exist between 2 start/end values in another column for each row. Say I have the below dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'39' : [1, np.nan, 3],
                   '40' : [2, 4, 5],
                   '41' : [3, 1, 4],
                   '42' : [2, 5, 2],
                   '43' : [1, 1, np.nan],
                   'start' : [39, 40, 41],
                   'end' : [41, 41, 43]})

    39  40  41  42  43  start  end
0  1.0   2   3   2   1     39   41
1  NaN   4   1   5   1     40   41
2  3.0   5   4   2   3     41   43
```

I want to put a nan in the numbered columns that aren't between the start/end column numbers (inclusive), to get the below:

```
    39   40  41   42  43  start  end
0  1.0  2.0   3  NaN NaN     39   41
1  NaN  4.0   1  NaN NaN     40   41
2  NaN  NaN   4  2.0 3.0     41   43
```

The only way I can currently think of doing this would be to iterate through the rows or columns to check if between start and end or not, but I know iterating through dataframes is bad practice.  I could turn the columns into lists and iterate through those and reassign, but I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve this?

Edit: I should note that the numerical columns are week numbers, so it is possible for them to go over a year (e.g. 51, 52, 1, 2, 3 then start could be 51, and end could be 1). I'm wondering if I need to make a list of the column numbers to keep before doing this, as using < or > won't work for this case.

An example of this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'51' : [1, np.nan, 3],
                   '52' : [2, 4, 5],
                   '1' : [3, 1, 4],
                   '2' : [2, 5, 2],
                   '3' : [1, 1, 3],
                   'start' : [51, 52, 52],
                   'end' : [1, 2, 1]})

    51  52  1  2  3  start  end
0  1.0   2  3  2  1     51    1
1  NaN   4  1  5  1     52    2
2  3.0   5  4  2  3     52    1
```

Output:

```
    51  52  1    2   3  start  end
0  1.0   2  3  NaN NaN     51    1
1  NaN   4  1  5.0 NaN     52    2
2  NaN   5  4  NaN NaN     52    1
```

Comment: I see edit, is possible change data sample for it? Then seems both solution failed.

Comment: @jezrael Yeah, will add another example. Sorry, forgot to add that note originally. I think maybe I need a list  of columns to keep each time instead

Comment: hmmm, possible soluton should be add year like `200151, 200152, 200201, 200202, 200203`, not sure if posible in your solution

Comment: @jezrael yes, I could add year into the column names if there isn't another way to do it. I was wondering if I could make a list of column names, and then start at the matching start and end at the matching end, then keep is everything inbetween and including

Comment: yop, it working, added to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy solutionwith compare between start and end :

```
df.columns = df.columns[:-2].astype(int).tolist() + df.columns[-2:].tolist()

s = df['start'].to_numpy()
e = df['end'].to_numpy()
cols = df.columns[:-2].to_numpy()

m = (s[:, None] <= cols) & (e[:, None] >= cols)

df.iloc[:, :-2] = df.iloc[:, :-2].where(m)
print (df)
    39   40  41   42  43  start  end
0  1.0  2.0   3  NaN NaN     39   41
1  NaN  4.0   1  NaN NaN     40   41
2  NaN  NaN   4  2.0 NaN     41   43
```

EDIT: If not possible compare by value with cumulative sum, for `e` from back and test if `1` in both masks:

```
s = df['start'].astype(str).to_numpy()
e = df['end'].astype(str).to_numpy()

cols = df.columns[:-2].to_numpy()

m1 = np.cumsum((s[:, None] == cols), axis=1) == 1
m2 = np.cumsum((e[:, None] == cols[::-1]), axis=1)[:, ::-1] == 1

m = m1 & m2
df.iloc[:, :-2] = df.iloc[:, :-2].where(m)
print (df)
    51  52  1    2   3  start  end
0  1.0   2  3  NaN NaN     51    1
1  NaN   4  1  5.0 NaN     52    2
2  NaN   5  4  NaN NaN     52    1
```

Comment: This definitely works on the example I gave, but when I try to transfer it over to my actual example, it just covers everything with Nan and I'm not entirely sure why, I think it's something to with s[:, None] being strings, but the column names are integers, so they don't match?

Comment: @EmiOB - exactly, in my solution are added `.astype(str)` for match with columns names also strings, maybe need remove it. In `s = df['start'].astype(str).to_numpy()
e = df['end'].astype(str).to_numpy()` to `s = df['start'].to_numpy()
e = df['end'].to_numpy()`

Answer (score 3):

We can make use of `stack` and `unstack` here:

```
df = df.set_index(["start", "end"]).stack()
idx = df.index
values = idx.get_level_values(2).astype(int)
start = idx.get_level_values(0)
end = idx.get_level_values(1)

df.where((values >= start) & (values <= end)).unstack().reset_index()
```

```
   start  end   39   40   41   42  43
0     39   41  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN NaN
1     40   41  NaN  4.0  1.0  NaN NaN
2     41   43  NaN  NaN  4.0  2.0 NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for column in ['39', '40', '41', '42', '43']:
    df[column].loc[(float(column) < df['start']) | (float(column) > df['end'])] = np.NaN
```

will print:

```
    39   40   41   42  43  start  end
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN NaN     39   41
1  NaN  4.0  1.0  NaN NaN     40   41
2  NaN  NaN  4.0  2.0 NaN     41   43
```